# What is the appropriate preposition to use to show preference?

Tags: prepositions

Which prepositions would be appropriate here ?

***She has a preference ......tea .......coffee. ***

(I think the first one would be "for" but can't decide whether it should be "to" or "over" for the second one)

Comment: It would almost always be more "appropriate" (natural, idiomatic) to say she [prefers tea to coffee](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prefers+tea+to+coffee%22). Or [prefers tea **over** coffee](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prefers+tea+over+coffee%22) (less than half as common, but still perfectly acceptable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> She has a preference for tea over coffee.

But

> She prefers tea to coffee.

Answer (score 0):

*For* is the most common preposition used with *preference*.

> She has a preference **for** coffee.

For comparison purposes:

> She has a preference **for* tea **over** coffee.